# Supplying the number of lambdas in cv.glmnet

Tags: lasso, glmnet

The `cv.glmnet` function states 2 options for its `lambda` parameter. First is `NULL`, and then `glmnet` chooses the lambda sequence such that the number of nonzero coefficients ranges from 0 to `p`, where `p` is the total number of features. And the second option is that the users can supply their own sequences. However, I think a third option where I supply the length of the sequence might be very helpful, such that the number of selected features still ranges from 0 to `p`, but the number of tested lambdas is dependent on the parameter I supplied. The second option is not always good since it is hard to guess which lambda gives the sparsest or densest model, so one can easily supply a not-very-useful sequence of lambdas. So, is there a way to give the number of lambda values to use in `cv.glmnet`?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out. There is the `nlambda` parameter in `glmnet()` function which also applies to `cv.glmnet()`.

Comment: It seems that you can't fully chose the nlambda, I have a lasso with `cv.glmnet` function which usually test 61 lambda values. When I specify `nlambda=100`, it still tests 61 values (it makes sense but for practical reasons it may be useful to know upstream the right number of lambda tested). I also tried `nlambda=50` but it tested 33 values. Do you know why ; and do you know if there is a way to force the number of lambda tested? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To add to the last comment, sometimes the number of evaluated lambdas can be lower than the manually specified number.

The glmnet documentation states that "Sometimes the sequence is truncated before nlambda values of lambda have been used. This happens when glmnet.path detects that the decrease in deviance is marginal (i.e. we are near a saturated fit)"